# How to Sort Products Based on Custom Attribute in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, product-collection, sorting

I would like to sort front end products in a category based on the custom attribute (say promote). I give value for promote attribute for every product in the website like 1,2,3,4,5..100,101..1000 etc. Here the requirement is, products need to be sorted based on the integer value irrespective of the category it exists. For example: If the promote attribute value is 1 then it should be the first product where ever category it exists. In other way highest promote attribute value should be top of every category. Please guide me in this.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create an attribute of type "**text field**". Let's name it "**Promote**" as you suggest
2. Be sure that you have "**Used in Product Listing**" and "**Used for Sorting in Product Listing**" set to "**Yes**"
3. Go to `System / Configuration / Catalog / Catalog / Frontend` you’ll see “**Product Listing Sort by**” drop down menu. Select your attribute
4. In any/every category, in the "**Display Settings**" tab, be sure that the field "**Default Product Listing Sort By**" has either your attribute selected or the checkbox "**Use Config Settings**" checked
5. Reindex and refresh Cache

Comment: I know the procedure you explained, but my requirement is I give positions for every product and they have to sort according to the given positions irrespective of the categories they present. For Example: Product A position is 1 so this product should always occupy first position in which ever category it presents. Thanks

Comment: But this is what you get with this method.